# How to display a decoded(using VP8 software decoder) stream of video, stored in a buffer, on surfaceView

Tags: android, video

I am working on a project like that of skype for android..
I have implemented the decoding of received data and display using surfaceView and mediacodec. 
But many devices supports only H264 decoding. So I have a software decoder for decoding VP8 video streams which decodes data and puts into a global buffer. Now I want to display that decoded stream using surface view (it was done using openGL but it is very slow).
But not getting an idea to do it using surfaceView.
Do anyone have an idea on how to render a decoded video stream to a surface of surfaceView.

Thanks a lot....................

Comment: Can I have some suggessions... I am trying it with canvas and bitmap but not yet succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer

```
bitmapSurface = Bitmap.createBitmap(320, 240, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmapSurface.copyPixelsFromBuffer(ByteBuffer.wrap(argb_frame));   
c = myVideoSurfaceView.getHolder().lockCanvas();
bitmapSurface = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapSurface,surflp.width, surflp.height, true);
c.drawBitmap(bitmapSurface, 0, 0, null);
myVideoSurfaceView.getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```